# Encoding error in QT Creator when including glm header files

Tags: c++, qt, glm-math

I'm including GLM header files in a QT project in QTCreator, but I keep getting encoding errors. All files seem to be set to  UTF-8 and they are displayed normally on screen. I get several messages as the following:

```
C:\Users\Luís Longo\OneDrive\Dyno3D\linking\glm\detail\type_mat2x3.inl:-1: In member function 'glm::mat<2, 3, T, Q>::col_type& glm::mat<2, 3, T, Q>::operator[](glm::mat<2, 3, T, Q>::length_type)':
C:\Users\Luís Longo\OneDrive\Dyno3D\linking\glm\detail\type_mat2x3.inl:222: error: converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence
assert(i < this->length());
^
```

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui opengl
LIBS     += -lopengl32
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/linking/glm
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
    GLPanel.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    GLPanel.h \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES += \
    fragment.glsl \
    vertex.glsl
```

OpenGL Widget class

````
#ifndef GLPANEL_H
#define GLPANEL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include "glm.hpp"

class GLPanel : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    GLPanel(QWidget* parent);
protected:
    void initializeGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
    void paintGL() override;
private:
    void InitializeOpenGLOptions();
};

#endif // GLPANEL_H```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was due to the filepath, which has a "í" character. Changing the project folder has solved the problem.